# OpenSSL DTLS1_SEND_SERVER_KEY_EXCHANGE:reason(50)

Tags: openssl

I have such error when using OpenSSL:

> SSL_accept: 1410B032: error:1410B032:SSLroutines:DTLS1_SEND_SERVER_KEY_EXCHANGE:reason(50)

I want to get reason of this error in string, but function ERR_reason_error_string() returns null. This mean there are no such reason in array of reasons.

Who can something say about this problem? What is this problem? When this problem may occur?
I can't understand reason.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a minimal test case to reproduce the behavior? What version of OpenSSL is the client using? And what version is the server using?

Comment: This problem occurs in the course of work programs (server and client), but it's very hard to reproduce this behavior (at this moment I can't do this). Version of OpenSSL is 1.0.0. Server uses the same version.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> error:1410B032:SSLroutines:DTLS1_SEND_SERVER_KEY_EXCHANGE:reason(50)
> ...
> I want to get reason of this error in string, but function ERR_reason_error_string() returns null.
> ```

Well, it looks like a bug in the library around error reporting (if I am reading the sources correctly).

---

> Who can something say about this problem? What is this problem? When
> this problem may occur? I can't understand reason.

`DTLS1_SEND_SERVER_KEY_EXCHANGE` is used in `ssl/d1_srvr.c`. For example:

```
SSLerr(SSL_F_DTLS1_SEND_SERVER_KEY_EXCHANGE,SSL_R_ERROR_GENERATING_TMP_RSA_KEY);
```

And:

```
SSLerr(SSL_F_DTLS1_SEND_SERVER_KEY_EXCHANGE,SSL_R_MISSING_TMP_RSA_KEY);
```

However, looking at `ssl/ssl.h` and the reason codes, there is no *Reason 50*. They start numbering at 100. From around line 2285:

```
/* Reason codes. */
#define SSL_R_APP_DATA_IN_HANDSHAKE            100
#define SSL_R_BAD_ALERT_RECORD                 101
#define SSL_R_BAD_AUTHENTICATION_TYPE          102
#define SSL_R_BAD_CHANGE_CIPHER_SPEC           103
```

It could be a TLS/DTLS alert I suppose. In that case, 50 is `decode_error` (see [RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246), Section 7.2). But I'm not convinced its the problem since alerts are usually reported properly.

Comment: What interesting. When this problem occurs and when other client want connect to server in log I see: Peer suddenly disconnected. By the code this log is being written when there are no errors, but some errors occur in connection between server and client too.

Comment: Its UDP. There's never a connection. Its fire and forget.

Comment: `there is no Reason 50`
I also tried to find this reason in code, but really there are no such code of reason.
I forgot to write, that OpenSSL is used with rewritten stunel. But how stunel can affect on occuring this problem? Stunel causes functions of OpenSSL, therefore in some moment it can transmit some wrong values in params. But what are wrong values can be transmitted? And where? In what place?